# How do certain Python packages modify/add to methods of other packages?

Tags: python

For eg: Pandas provides a `DataFrame` object with the `apply` method. Installing another package Pandarallel provides the same pandas DataFrame object with a new `parallel_apply` method. How is this achieved?

Comment: You can see the source code.

Comment: @bichanna good idea

Answer (score 1):

Most objects are mutable. It just adds more properties to the classes.

For example,

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter('abc')
try:
   c.foo()  # AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'foo'
except e:
   pass
c.foo = lambda: print('hello')
c.foo()  # prints hello
```

For a more explicit answer, look at the source code - https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel/blob/master/pandarallel/pandarallel.py#L572

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you add a method to a class, all objects created prior to this would also have the new method.

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()

A.m = lambda self, x: x

# This returns 5!!
a.m(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't appear to be the technique used in your referenced package, one way is that [class objects can inherit from other class objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

So in a separate package, you can create a new `CustomDataFrame` class:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
class CustomDataFrame(DataFrame):
"""Custom dataframe with new method"""
    def new_func(self, x):
        print(x)

df = CustomDataFrame()
df.new_func("new function that prints")  # --> prints "new function that prints"
```

`CustomDataFrame` will have all the attributes of the original base class `DataFrame`, plus the `CustomDataFrame.new_func()` method.

Naming the derived class with the same name as the base class is also possible, and new methods created with the same name will override the base class method.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
class DataFrame(DataFrame):
"""Custom dataframe with new method"""
    # methods of same name will override the base class
    def apply(self):
        print("df.apply() overridden")

df = DataFrame()
df.apply()  # --> prints "df.apply() overridden"
```